# cURL equivalent in Java

Tags: java, curl

I had

```
exec(
  "curl".
  " --cert $this->_cCertifikatZPKomunikace".
  " --cacert $this->_cCertifikatPortalCA".
  " --data \"request=".urlencode($fc_xml)."\"".
  " --output $lc_filename_stdout".
  " $this->_cPortalURL".
  " 2>$lc_filename_stderr",
  $la_dummy,$ln_RetCode
);
```

in php.

I have to do it via java. Can you help me?

Thanks Jakub

Comment: Another option: https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/

Answer (score 14):

I use the HttpClient methods:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
```

like so:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("http://www.google.com");
int responseCode = client.executeMethod(method);
if (responseCode != 200) {
    throw new HttpException("HttpMethod Returned Status Code: " + responseCode + " when attempting: " + url);
}
String rtn = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(method.getResponseBodyAsString());
```

EDIT: Oops. StringEscapeUtils comes from commons-lang. http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: HTTPClient is great but the code you show would fail as it does not address certs...

Comment: I went to apache. httpcomponents have been shut down instead of you now import `org.apache.httpclient.*`. I downloaded entire package, imported it. It gave me around 100 errors. When I saw them, they were all in classes of that package. In the downloaded package `commons` was nowhere to be found. And some classes in it were trying to import `org.apache.commons.*` when there is no commons folder !!! What is this ??

Comment: This is a question answered a long time ago. Things changed and this isn't the correct approach anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [URLConnection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html). Sun has some [examples](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html). It has various subclasses that support some specific HTTP and HTTPS features.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to the pure Java answers by Quotidian and Yacoby you can try to execute the curl binary as in php. Check out how to use the `ProcessBuilder` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute commands in Java by using the `Runtime` with a call to `getRuntime()`

link to the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) for Runtime.

[Here's](http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2003/tt0304.html) a decent example of using Runtime.

[Here's](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html) a decent example using Runtime or ProcessBuilder.

I hope some of that is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The cURL site links to [Java Bindings](https://github.com/pjlegato/curl-java) on Github.

Comment: Yeah but then it wouldn't be a pure java solution, which is (IMO) the major advantage of Java.

Comment: (+1) yeah but it would make working with certs easy and it would translate from his original call rather nicely.

Comment: The provided link is dead

Comment: @Thibault I've updated the link to the bindings new location on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) API in Java

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
```

like so:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage homePage = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
String homePageString = homePage.asXml();
```