# Programmatically reading Web pages opened in Internet Explorer by Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer

There is some pages opened in Internet explorer and i wanted to  read HTML of those pages by Core Java Application.
There is a lot of material to load the URL and read HTML web pages in java but i am not getting any clue to read the pages's source code that is already opened in Internet Explorer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apache Commons HttpClient package([hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)).  [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156431/curl-equivalent-in-java) to how it is used from another stack overflow posting

Comment: Apache's HTTP Client provide  mechanism to communicate over web, but my scenario is that some page is opened in IE and i want to see their HTML source code and i wanted to do it by java program(Core Java), but not getting any point to think upon it.